# Possible CW question

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The possibility of converting [European Ph.D. student salary range web site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42869/european-ph-d-student-salary-range-web-site) to a community wiki has been raised. What do people think?

Answer (score 2):

I am personally against the community wiki (although as a mod, I will do what people vote for). My reasoning is that there is variation with countries, universities and schools, making "correct" answers difficult. Verification of the data will also be difficult. Further, the salaries will change over time which means each answer will need to be consistently update so as not to fall out of date.

Comment: I do not agree. a little and verity information is better than nothing :) isn't?

Comment: @alex maybe, you can make a case for it as an answer here. CW questions  are "exceptions" to what is usually appropriate for SE. I personally think that we should only make exceptions for things that are exceptionally good/important. This question doesn't seem to qualify in my personal opinion.